# android problem in getting the screen resolution size

Tags: android, screen

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
Log.e("FirstImage", "Width = "+width+"Height = "+height);
```

The above was the code I have used to display the screen size.. but the problem is I am getting `width=320` and `height=569`. But I am using motorola milestone with screen size `480x854`

How can I get the correct size?

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
width = display.getWidth();
height = display.getHeight();
orientation=display.getOrientation();  i have used this code too but same problem exist  ANY one please help me its very urgent for my application

Comment: Conclusion about how to get real resolution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824193/htc-sensation-real-resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://realmike.org/blog/2010/12/21/multiple-screen-sizes-with-processing-for-android/

above link has excellent resource that tells about the screen resolution and how to get the real screen resolution etc....read fully you will come to know about the reality

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the supporting of larger screens, you'll get this i'm afraid, because the screen is pretending to be smaller to be able to show the app (that is supposed to not support your big screen).

If you add this to your manifest it will show the correct values

```
     <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
     />
```

you might even want to play with the

```
 android:anyDensity
```

attribute, but I don't think it is needed for your current problem.

Comment: (seriously, i had your problem, this was the cause :)  )

Comment: where did you put in in your manifest? Again, same problem, same phone (the first milestone) and large screen support was the issue

Comment: is the resolution and screen size are different or same?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int height = d.getHeight();
```

Comment: Would that give a different value then the method he's using above? (just curious)

Comment: @Nanne: I'm pretty sure that's the exact same thing as the original method, just a different method of acquiring the WindowManager.

Answer (score 0):

The `<supports-screens>` tag should definitely work. See

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

An important question is, why don't you trust the scaled dimensions you're getting from the DisplayMetrics?  If you were to do something like

```
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,width,height), new Paint());
```

Your rectangle would certainly fill the screen.  There's a scaling happening, but maybe you don't care.