# HTC Sensation Real Resolution

Tags: android, resolution

I have two approaches to get real resolution:

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    device_value[index++] = dm.widthPixels + "x" + m.heightPixels;

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    String widthAndHeight = display.getWidth() + " x " + display.getHeight();

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  android:targetSdkVersion="3"/>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

Both of them return "320x569" while the real one is "640x960".

Comment: tried * density: dm.widthPixels * dm.density

Comment: no, real resolution for HTC Sensation is 540x960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion about how to get real resolution:

```
< uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="4"...

< supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"...

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
String resolution = dm.widthPixels + "x" + m.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because your target or minimum SDK version is activating Screen Compatibility Mode. You should use higher minimum and target SDK values in your manifest.